# Storing login information to online database in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, authentication, web, storage

I'm making an application which needs the user to log in. I want to know how to store the login details (username & password) into an online database (please suggest me which one to use also). I'm new in this field so can anybody help me with how to start?

Comment: create a sql database in server and connect it with webservise.

Comment: @Signare can u provide me with a tutorial or sth like that please? I dont really know how to connect blackberry to a webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to store into online server then you need to post your data to server Using HTTP Post method with web service.You need to make submit your  details using HTTP Post please refer following link

[How to post data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598045/914111)

Otherwise you want to store your Login data into your Phone itself then you have two ways

1)persistent storage please refer following link

[persistent storage in blackberry tutorials](http://blackberrytutor.info/tutorials/37-general/49-persistent-storage)

2)On sdcard using sqlite database  please refer following link

[sqlite in blackberry tutorials](http://mobijournal.com/blackberry-sqlite-tutorial/)

All the best if you more doubts please visit this room we will help you

[Blackberry room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java)

Comment: How to create a server? Do I need to create a website? Sorry I'm very new in IT